# Load SwipeBox gallery and open external link

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink

```
<li>
    <a rel="gallery-3" href="images/photos/photo7.jpg" title="Photo title" class="swipebox">
       <img src="images/photos/photo7.jpg" alt="image"/>
    </a>
</li>
```

How can I insert and open an external link in swipebox  (redirect to another url when click on an image), I've tried all day long and google searched, but I can't click on an img in swipebox.

This is the url: http://azparts.epizy.com/blix/#!/photos.html

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you posted does exactly what you want. It opens the new url that is defined in href of the anchor tag - in your case the image url.

**Working example:**

```html
<a rel="gallery-3" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196" title="Photo title" class="swipebox">
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196" alt="image" />
</a>
```

---

Instead of the image url you can also define any other url, for example for stackoverflow.

**Working example:**

```html
<a rel="gallery-3" href="https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask" title="Photo title" class="swipebox">
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196" alt="image"/>
</a>
```

In your special swipebox case the link works if you have the class "swipebox" in the anchor tag. The image will then be opened in a lightbox. But this only works when the href of the link points to the image url. It also works for my stackoverflow example snippet, but the image is not loaded because it's from another server - error: "Cross-Origin Read Blocking" (see console in browser developer tools). The anchor around photo2.png has no class="swipebox" and therefor doesn't work in swipebox...

Comment: i've try this, but it don't work, you can check my demo [demo][1]


  [1]: http://azparts.epizy.com/blix/index.html#!/photos.html

Comment: I updated my answer after inspecting your page and also added your page link to your question...

Comment: and finally, it can't be open external link by click img in swipebox ? So, how if i dont want open img in lightbox,, just click img and redirect to external link, how i can code ?

Comment: Yes, i think so. But maybe you find a solution in the [documentation](https://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/) or in the issue blog of the swipbox-github-page [Open external images via swipebox?](https://github.com/brutaldesign/swipebox/issues/326) (it was the second google result for "*swipebox external link*")...

Comment: Thank you very much @biberman, have a nice day.

Comment: If it answers your question you should mark it as accepted...